# Data passed to prepareForSegue is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm trying to get `IngredientViewController` to update an array belongs to the controller that called it via the segue (`FridgeViewController`)

In `IngredientViewController` fridgeManager is nil no matter what I try

The code:

**FridgeViewController:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    IngredientViewController *controller = (IngredientViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [controller setFridgeManager:fridgeManager];
}
```

**IngredientViewController:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FridgeDataManager *fridgeManager;
```

and in viewDidLoad `fridgeManager` is nil (and in any other method of coarse)

Comment: Make sure synthesize,fridgeManager.

Comment: nice try... it is a valid object

Comment: @Ramdy - can you elaborate?

Comment: synthesize this fridgeManager property in IngredientViewController.m like @synthesize fridgeManager;

Comment: What reason do you have to pass this object like this? You could just make a singleton and store in in there. You can easily access it from anywhere then and you can make sure it always have an initial value.

Comment: Well... You are all right. It is the damn xcode bug. po fridgeManager in the debugger was OK. Ramdy - you are somehow right - needed to _fridgeManager

Comment: ya, _fridgeManager is right, its equal to @synthesize fridgeManager; If you synthesize the property means, no need to use "_"

Comment: What version of xcode you're using,normally Xcode automatically synthesize properties.

Comment: Hey Boaz, just wonder, are you implementing the food keeping app that helps to manage food? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

synthesize this **fridgeManager** property in **IngredientViewController.m**

```
@synthesize fridgeManager;
```

Comment: Theeya ulaikanum nalla thambi.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Xcode, you don't need to synthesize your properties, OR create an instance variable. If you don't do either, then Xcode creates an instance variable with a "_" prefix to match your property. (I believe this was is a change that was part of Objective C 2.0.)

So

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *foo;
```

Gives you an instance variable of `_foo.

And you could use it like:

```
[controller setFridgeManager: _foo];
```

If you have both a property fridgeManager and an instance variable fridgeManager, they are likely different entities, so setting

```
fridgeManager = x;
```

Would change a different instance variable than setting

```
self.fridgeManager = x;
```